# Aborting loading of script if HTTP Basic Auth fails

Tags: html, http, authentication

I'm loading a cross-origin script that requires a username/password using HTTP Basic Access Authentication.

I'm not concerned with the security of the username/password. My code:

```
<script src="http://user:password@example.com/script.js"></script>
```

This works fine in most cases. However, if the credentials are incorrect, an authentication dialog pops up.

I would like to abort the loading of the script if the credentials are wrong instead of presenting the authentication dialog to the user. Ideally a JavaScript function would be triggered as well to alert that something has gone wrong.

Is this possible, and how would it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think this would fall on the server-side configuration.

Instead of sending a `HTTP 401 Not Authorized` with `WWW-Authenticate` header, the server should respond with a different status code, perhaps `403 Forbidden`

The problem is that when a `401` is sent to the browser, the browser interprets that as a login requirement, prompting the user.  If it receives another error status (i.e. `403`) it will simply error out (which can be caught by a JavaScript function)

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I don't have control of the server. I'm just wondering if there's any JavaScript I can use, even if it's a bit messy, to detect the `401` (or just any error) without the user having to click `Cancel`.

Comment: You could use JavaScript to dynamically load the script instead of using a script tag.  You could then catch the 401 error.  If you want to do that, consider `XMLHttpRequest` or a library that includes ajax js loading. caveat: scripts that depend on your loaded script may fail since script tag order is no longer guaranteed for async loading. You should call any dependent scripts in a onsuccess callback